# javascript custom date display (stardate) not working

Tags: javascript

I'm making a stardate display for a site. I'm using the new StarTrek Into Darkness stardate because the STTNG used the season number and no real 1:1 relationship with time, while the new STID does. Here's my code.

```
function stardate() {
int theYear=0;
int theDay

var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();

Date.prototype.dayOfYear= function(){
var j1= new Date(this);
j1.setMonth(0, 0);
return Math.round((this-j1)/8.64e7);
return new Date().dayofYear();
}
theDay = Number(dayOfYear);

theYear = Number(year - 2015 + 2415);

return "Stardate: " + theYear.ToString + "." + theDay.ToString;

}
```

And then the HTML that I'm using to display it is here:

```
<div id="stardate" alight="right">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("stardate").innerHTML = stardate().ToString +
'</p>';
</script>
</div>
```

Is there something obvious I'm not doing right?

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos like `ToString`.

Also `toString` (with lower case t) is a method, so you would have to call it with parens: `.toString()`.

If you do not add the parens to the method, you will pass the function's reference and not its result, like in `theDay = Number(dayOfYear);`. Here you would have to add parens to the method `dayOfYear`: `theDay = Number(today.dayOfYear());` (also added `today.` because you've declared the method `dayOfYear` as a `Date`'s method.

You also declared variables with the `int` keyword, but in JavaScript there is not typed variables. You should only use the keywork `var` for this.

The working code:

```js
function stardate() {
  var theYear = 0;
  var theDay;

  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  Date.prototype.dayOfYear = function() {
    var j1 = new Date(this);
    j1.setMonth(0, 0);
    return Math.round((this - j1) / 8.64e7);
  }

  theDay = Number(today.dayOfYear());

  theYear = Number(year - 2015 + 2415);

  return "Stardate: " + theYear.toString() + "." + theDay.toString();
}

document.getElementById("stardate").innerHTML = '<p>' + stardate() + '</p>';
```

```html
<div id="stardate" alight="right"></div>
```